# IF statement doesn't work properly in osascript

Tags: macos, applescript, bash

I'm working on script which should do something if application is running or not Also there should be a timer of checking(60 seconds) The problem is that "if" statement which is checking "count" doesn't work.

Here is a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e "do shell script \"

COUNT="0"

while true;
do
    if (ps aux | grep Skype | grep -v grep > /dev/null)
    then
        echo "RUNNING" > /Users/someuser/Desktop/RUNNING.txt
    else
        echo "STOPPED" > /Users/someuser/Desktop/STOPPED.txt
    fi

    sleep 1
    COUNT=$((COUNT+1))

    if (("$COUNT" > "60"))
    then
        exit 0
    fi

done

\" with administrator privileges"
```

Comment: Where are You increasing `$COUNT`? It's always 0.

Comment: updated code above

Comment: The next thing: does it even work for You? You have so many `"` inside the script and in my opinion this should not work. Increasing `$COUNT` is also done in the wrong way (missing `$`). `if` statements uses `[ ... ]` not `( ... )` in bash.

Comment: yes, it works for me without any errors. I run it in terminals using: "sh my_script.sh"

Comment: Are you really only interested in the exit code of the last `grep` in the if statement? Or do you want base the decision on the fact whether "Skype" appears in the output of `ps` or not?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Inside `$((...))`, variables don't need a leading `$`. Also `if` just acts on the exit code of a command which usually is `[` (for test), but basically any command works.

Comment: Your quoting is all wrong too…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way works:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e do shell script \"

COUNT=0

while true;
do
    if (ps aux | grep Skype | grep -v grep > /dev/null)
    then
        echo 'RUNNING' > /Users/someuser/Desktop/RUNNING.txt
    else
        echo 'STOPPED' > /Users/someuser/Desktop/STOPPED.txt
    fi

    sleep 1
    COUNT=$((COUNT+1))

    if (($COUNT > 60))
    then
        exit 0
    fi

done
\" with administrator privileges
```

- You don't need the quotes before `do shell script`, as this is an applescript sentence.
- Avoid unnecessary double quotes to prevent errors.